# Need guidance on achieving smooth edges and round corners for a case model in Blender 3.3.1

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, topology, bevel, smooth

Title: Need guidance on achieving smooth edges and round corners for a case model in Blender 3.3.1

Hello Blender community,

I'm relatively new to Blender and I'm currently working on creating a model of a case. My goal is to achieve a design where the front of the case has rounded corners, while the rest of the case features smooth edges.
[image: Model]

To create the round corners, I used a cylinder to cut out the desired shape. The case itself is now complete, but I'm facing challenges when it comes to making all the edges of the model smooth.

Initially, I attempted to use a bevel operation. However, this approach resulted in the entire model becoming distorted. I also experimented with applying a bevel modifier, but encountered similar issues. Adjusting parameters such as segments and other settings within the bevel menu didn't yield satisfactory results. I even tried eliminating duplicate vertices using the "Mesh" menu and the "Merge" operation based on distance.

[image: Adding Bevel]

As an alternative, I tried applying a Subdivision Surface modifier. While playing around with the viewport and render settings, the model ended up looking like this.

[image: Subdivision Surface modifier]

I suspect that the issues I'm encountering might be related to poor geometry in my model. I've referred to several resources, such as:

Recources:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itPxJ-GUNKQ ,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56MiL2FX6fk ,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdlcAD6FRpo&t=155s

However, I'm still struggling to achieve the desired results. Any advice or guidance on how to properly approach achieving smooth edges and round corners for my case model in Blender 3.3.1 would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

The updated file 18-08-2023: [image]

**UPDATE 17-08-23**

In my continuous pursuit of effective beveling, I've observed that when I apply a bevel solely to the top horizontal section of the model, it functions as intended. However, upon experimenting with multiple edges, things become awry.

Further, I've attempted to individually bevel each corner, yet this endeavor also results in undesirable distortions. Your expertise in unraveling these challenges would be sincerely valued.

[image: Bevel one piece]
[image: Bevel]
[image]

**UPDATE 18-08-23**

I have successfully merged the vertices and resolved the issue with the non-manifold geometry. However, I'm still facing a challenge with adding bevels to achieve the desired round and smooth corners. Interestingly, when I apply a bevel to the top part, it works for a single edge. But when I attempt to apply it to a second edge or multiple edges simultaneously, the model becomes distorted.

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: Do _Object > Apply > Scale_ and try the bevel again. For subdivision, have a look at edge creases and supporting edge loops. Else we need your file.

Comment: Where can i find the Objext > Apply > Scale, do you also mean the scale with the S hot key. I've also added the file.

Comment: @MaxBenen In *Object Mode* do this https://snipboard.io/aZ3gi0.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Tick the checkbox *Face Orientation* under *Viewport Overlays*. You have several problems like overlapping vertices & faces and internal faces. Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices then <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance* which will merge 4 overlapping vertices. Then you can easily see the internals of your mesh by selecting faces and pressing <kbd>H</kbd> to Hide them and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to Unhide the faces again once you are done cleaning up your mesh. Delete all internal faces and overlapping faces then fill faces properly again by selecting vertices or edges and pressing <kbd>F</kbd> to fill. Everything needs to look nice and blue, which means Face Normals are pointing outwards correctly. Then you can Bevel or use Subdivision modifier with Supporting Edges of course which can be added with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for [`Loop Cuts`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html).

[image]

Comment: Thanks to the tip about using 'H' to hide faces, I was able to eliminate the overlapping faces in my model, and it's looking much better now with a pleasant blue appearance.

However, I've encountered a new challenge. Despite the improvements I've made, I'm still facing issues when applying a bevel or Subdivision modifier. The model's geometry appears distorted and messy. I attempted to address this by adding loop cuts, but unfortunately, that didn't resolve the problem.

To provide a clearer picture of the situation, I'm going to update the file and share it for review.

Comment: can you share your new blend file?

Comment: In *Edit Mode* press `1` to go to *Vertex Mode* then go to *Select > Select All By Trait > Non Manifold*, you will see there are still 29 vertices selected that are problematic like underneath https://snipboard.io/QvDUSy.jpg

Comment: @Max Benen To add to Harry's answer, in Object mode you need to apply the scale and you need to merge some vertices like these ones: https://zupimages.net/up/23/33/llym.jpg

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I have successfully merged the vertices and resolved the issue with the non-manifold geometry. However, I'm still facing a challenge with adding bevels to achieve the desired round and smooth corners.

Interestingly, when I apply a bevel to the top part, it works for a single edge. But when I attempt to apply it to a second edge or multiple edges simultaneously, the model becomes distorted. I will attach the updated file to my question for further reference. Your insights and assistance are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also deleted some edge loops and fixed some triangles

Comment: @MaxBenen because you still didn't apply the scale as taiyo has already previously mentioned using *Object > Apply > Scale*. or press `Ctrl+A` in *Object Mode* and select *Scale*. like this https://snipboard.io/aZ3gi0.jpg